# How to configure ngnix (proxy server) with Angular and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, nginx, proxy

Im trying to make ngnix work with **NodeJS** and **Angular**.
At this moment, Im able to access **https://mypage/api** (Server API) and **https://mypage/** (Angular). However, when I try to log in with socket.io, i always have a '*Socket connection timed out error*'. I think this error occurs due to the reverse proxy technique. Am i missing any configuration file? Or setting a wrong header?

ngnix conf:

```
server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        all centificate letscrypt Stuff
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200/;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030/;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your location / block

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

This helped me while I configured the same, However I did not have the same issue you have. My socket connected alright but there was a handshake error and the socket would fallback on polling.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved adding these lines in **location /** block:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

However, your client should connect to the server excluding **http://** (or **https://** for SSL) protocol, and using only **server_name** or **ip address**, or by specifying the **ws://** (or **wss://** for SSL) protocol.